# What does "想問伊人何處" mean?

Tags: translation

There's this song in Chinese with these lyrics.

```
起雲動劍下虎嘯龍吟
誰知成敗早已是天定
想問伊人何處
離愁漸遠漸生
但願人長久情常在
無悔無憾
```

What does the phrase "想問伊人何處" mean and connote? I understand this song to be sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

伊人 is lover.

想問伊人何處 means: I want to ask where is my lover.

Answer (score 2):

伊人 may be means 'my lover'.

also can means 'a beautiful girl who he will fall in love with'

note that he is very sad, he failed in competition, and he need a girl to comfort him.